# Parse an content-type header from http request stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the contents of an http request saved on disk.

It looks like this:

> POST http://test.ca/ 1.1 
> Accept: application/xml 
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="8942d141-7753-45ab-be3a-53021694e70c"
>
> --8942d141-7753-45ab-be3a-53021694e70c
> Content-Type: application/xml Content-Disposition: form-data; name=Bundle
>
> ...
> --8942d141-7753-45ab-be3a-53021694e70c 
> Content-Type: image/jpg Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image 1 of 2"; filename=Attachment1.jpg; filename*=utf-8''Attachment1.jpg
>
> ...
> --8942d141-7753-45ab-be3a-53021694e70c--

Normally, if you were processing this at the time of request, the HttpRequest object would be used to get the content type.   If I have that request persisted to disk,  are there any available classes I can use to handle parsing the ContentType for me?

Everything else can be parsed using the MultipartReader class, but I'm not aware of anything that will handle parsing the request header, given an instance of a stream.  If I don't have to roll my own that would be great.

Comment: Could you not use [compose the request](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-compose-https-requests-with-fiddler) in fiddler to do this?

Comment: @JohnH - I need to do this programmatically.  It is during consumption of the message, not at creation

Comment: Alright, I asked in case you are wanted to replay a request from production on your local to figure something out.

Comment: How was the request serialized to disk? Was it using your code or a third party?

Comment: @audzzy - 3rd party